# I can't access my wordpress site on localhost

Tags: wordpress, localhost

[image: screenshot of the problem]

My wordpress localhost is not working.It shows that , "there has been a critical error on this website.

Learn more about troubleshooting WordPress."

Answer (score 0):

set WP_DEBUG TO TRUE in your wp-config.php file, should give you more detail on the error.  And you troubleshoot from there, or update this so we can help you to resolve it.